# From localhost to intranet site, using XAMPP and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost, intranet

I want to create an intranet (very simple) site using XAMPP and wordpress,
so I started installing XAMPP on my PC (localhost) and writing a simple page with wordpress: everything fine so far.
Now I need to access to my site (named "sitetest01") from another PC on the LAN, so I followed some tutorials on the net, without successing on it.

1) I modified \Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, adding:
   192.168.10.126       intranet.local

2) C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf, adding:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\sitetest01"
ServerName intranet.local
</VirtualHost>
```

3) So on the browser on my PC, setting "intranet.local" it seems to work....but

[it seems to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2iRC.jpg)

4) ..but clicking on the link "Ciao mondo", an error occurred and
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAWnJ.jpg)

5) What I have to do ?
Thx 
Andrea

Comment: As always for internal errors: start reading the http servers error log file.

Answer (score 0):

You need change the url of  wordpreess in the database for example in the table options you need change the url of site for you ip options:

[image: options]

*Second image:*

[image]

Also you need change the url´s of images and folders, all change of de database.

Comment: I changed: table _options and _posts as You told me: http://localhost/sitetest01 ==> http://myipaddress/sitetest01. Now The error is stil present when clickking the link of post, and the home page is similar to "text page" (I don't' know how to add picture in comments). Do I miss some _table or other steps should be done ?